# Using multiple add() commands in a select object

Tags: javascript, addition

I am trying to create a website that changes its `<option>` in a `<form>` based on user input in a previous `<form>`. My mock-up is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <select id="select">
    <option>Car</option>
    <option>Phone</option>
  </select>
</form>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Get new list</button>

<form>
  <select id="results">
  </select>
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("select").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("results");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    if (x == "Car")
    {
        for(i = 0; i < document.getElementById("results").length; i++)
        {
            y.remove(y[i]);
        }

        option.text = "Honda";
        y.add(option);
        option.text = "Nissan";
        y.add(option);
        option.text = "BMW";
        y.add(option);
    }
    if (x == "Phone")
    {
        for(i = 0; i < document.getElementById("results").length; i++)
        {
            y.remove(y[i]);
        }

        option.text = "Blackberry";
        y.add(option);
        option.text = "Nokia";
        y.add(option);
        option.text = "Android";
        y.add(option);
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What I want this code to do is allow the user to pick Honda, Nissan, or BMW if they choose the Car option and pick either Blackberry, Nokia, or Android if they choose the Phone option. However the `add()` command only takes the last line of input (BMW, or Android). Am I going about this in the right way with just a simply fix needed, or should I rework how I approach this problem?

Also, how can I make it so they second form automatically populates without needing to click the button?

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the same option object each time - you need to create a new one using

```
option = document.createElement("option");
```

before each `option.text = "xxxx";` line.

E.g.

```
var option1 = document.createElement("option");
option1.text = "Honda";
y.add(option1);

var option2 = document.createElement("option");
option2.text = "Nissan";
y.add(option2);

// etc
```